# AWS ACM: Change/Replace SSL certificate on load balancer without downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have an existing Digicert certificate imported on an ALB. This will expire in some days. I want to move to AWS ACM obtained certificate on the load balancer instead of importing third party(Digicert) certificate. This way ACM will manage the renewal going forward.

So , I will get a new certificate for the domain from ACM and add it to the ALB's certificate list. My question is will the ALB pick this new one(ACM obtained) after the old one(Digicert) expires? Does this happen automatically without a downtime ?

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple certificates for the same domain associated with the load balancer. You will need to replace the current certificate association with the new one. There should be no down time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkB. lll try that and get back if any questions